# Writing long list using pandas to save in csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using the following to write to a csv file with python:

```
submission = pandas.DataFrame({
    "label": data["label"],
    predictors[0]: data[predictors[0]]
})
```

and later I write a csv file with:

```
submission.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

Now, my predictor list is a long list of 1000+ elements, and obviously I cannot write all those lines by hand

```
submission = pandas.DataFrame({
    "label": data["label"],
    predictors[0]: data[predictors[0]]
    predictors[1]: data[predictors[1]]
    predictors[2]: data[predictors[2]]
    predictors[3]: data[predictors[3]]

    ...
    })
```

I tried

```
submission = pandas.DataFrame({
    "label": data["label"],
    for i in range(lengthofpredictors):
       predictors[i]: data[predictors[i]]
})
```

but it does not work, as

```
submission = pandas.DataFrame({
    "label": data["label"],
    predictors: data[predictors]
})
```

won't work. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using list comprehension to create the dictionary?

```
tmp = dict([("label", data["label"])] + \
    [(predictors[i], data[predictors[i]]) for i in range(784)])
```

Then

```
 submission = pandas.DataFrame(tmp)
```

Comment: Ok, just a couple of typing mistakes, it should be: tmp = dict([("label", data["label"])] + [(predictors[i], data[predictors[i]]) for i in range(784)])
and then    
submission = pandas.DataFrame(tmp)